# Upgrade/update a node package in package.json without installing it?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

This question applies to either `npm` or `yarn` and I would like to know if what I need to do can be done with one or the other or both. For the sake of clarity I will only refer to `yarn` commands as I would prefer the `yarn` solution.

I have a bash script where I conditionally `yarn upgrade` a node package that is guaranteed to be in the `package.json` file but has not yet been installed. I would like to potentially reduce the number of times I call `yarn install`. As it stands I need to call `yarn install` and then `yarn upgrade` but I don't need to because I will be calling `yarn install` later in the script.

I think I can save a call to `yarn install` (via a `yarn upgrade`) in my script by simply updating the version number for the node package I want upgraded in `package.json` but then do not actually install any of those files since I will be calling `yarn install` at a later time in the script.

I would simply like to change the version number of a specific node package without installing any files using either a `yarn` or `npm` command. If this is not possible is this a good use case to parse `package.json` by hand and insert the version number with brute force?

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies can be added to your `package.json` without installing them by using [npm-add-dependencies](https://github.com/arfeo/npm-add-dependencies)

You can use it on-they-fly via `npx`, for example:

```sh
npx add-dependencies browser-sync-webpack-plugin@^2 browser-sync@^2 --dev
```

This will add `browser-sync-webpack-plugin` version `^2` and `browser-sync` version `2^` to `devDependencies` in your `package.json`